# How do I show that a function of two variables is increasing when one variable is increasing twice as fast as the other is decreasing?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I have the function $w_{engine, real} = \eta_{th} w_{engine, ideal}$ where $w$ is work done and $\eta_{th}$ is thermal efficiency. To show that $w_{engine, real}$ would decrease if $\eta_{th}$ was lowered while $w_{engine, ideal}$ stays constant, I would write: $$\frac{{\partial w_{engine, real}}}{{\partial \eta_{th}}} = w_{engine, ideal}$$ Since the variables only take positive value, the partial derivative would always be positive, and so $w_{engine, real}$ would change in the same direction as $\eta_{th}$ does, and so $w_{engine, real}$ would lower.

But when I have the situation where both variables change in the opposite direction but one is changing twice as fast as the other, let's say that $\eta_{th}$ is increasing twice as fast as $w_{engine, ideal}$ is decreasing, how do I show that $w_{engine, real}$ increases as a result? There is also an additional information that might matter: $0 \le \eta_{th} < 1$

I tried doing this:$$\vec v = \left\langle {\frac{2}{{\sqrt 5 }},- \frac{1}{{\sqrt 5 }}} \right\rangle$$ $${D_{\vec u}}w_{engine, real}\left( {\eta_{th},w_{engine, ideal}} \right)  = \left ( \frac{2}{\sqrt{5}} \right )w_{engine, ideal} - \left ( \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \right )\eta_{th}$$

I can say that since the variables only take positive value and $0 \le \eta_{th} < 1$, the directional derivative is always positive, but this alone doesn't show the direction that $w_{engine, real}$ would change. In the case above this one, I was able to use the direction of the change of $\eta_{th}$ and argue that since the partial derivative is positive, $w_{engine, real}$ would change in the same direction, because only one variable was allowed to vary in that case. But in the second case, both variables vary, in the opposite direction, albeit one is changing twice as fast as the other is.

Edit: The following is also always true here: $w_{engine, real} \le w_{engine, ideal}$

Comment: are you sure $w_{engine, real}$ will indeed increase as a result? It may decrease if $w_{engine, ideal} < \eta_{th}/2$

Comment: I don't think it is physically meaningful to say that a unitless quantity increases twice as fast as a quantity with units of work decreases. What if we change the units of work? I suspect that the actual problem you are trying to solve needs to be approached differently than the approach you have presented here, but we have no way of knowing what actual problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @whoisit Yes, $w_{engine,real}$ may (would?) decrease if $w_{engine,ideal} < \eta_{th}/2$. This is a caveat that I would like to include in my explanation. Although I am dealing with real-world values of work done by the engine and $w_{engine,ideal}$ is well above 1 kJ in the situation I am concerned with (so this reversal wouldn't occur), I don't completely understand why this would matter since I can just change the unit of $w_{engine,ideal}$ to make it less than $\eta_{th}/2$ (like from kJ to MJ).

Comment: @DavidK I only use this specific example because some extra information about the values that each variable can take might help answer my question. But it shouldn't matter what real-world quantities the two variables represent. I could've asked the same question using 'Area = (length)(width)'.

Comment: I think dimensions of measurement do matter. In the case of area = (length)(width), the two quantities have the same dimension, so it is possible to compare their rates of change by using the same units for each quantity. "I don't completely understand why this would matter since I can just change the unit of $w_{engine,ideal}$ to make it less than $η_{th}/2$ (like from kJ to MJ)." The fact that you **could** do this is exactly why it matters.

Comment: Perhaps you should consider the "relative" rate of increase on each side--that is, divide the derivative of each variable $v$ by the value of $v$, so "how fast" $v$ is changing is measured by $\frac 1v \frac{dv}{dt}.$ If you do that for each of the factors in your formula then you actually can compare these "relative" rates to decide which way the product is going. Alternatively, take the derivative of the logarithm of each variable; that has the same effect.

Comment: @DavidK But even in the case of area = (length)(width), you don't immediately know of a way to show that the area would increase if the length were to increase twice as fast as the rate at which the width decreases (we are only considering the case where the width isn't less than half of the length)? Even using directional derivative?

Comment: If the width is greater than half the length, yes, that actually will work and makes sense. But now that I think about it, why not just use the product rule for derivatives? It will tell you which way the function's value is going in all cases.